# DDlist with the ability to add text

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, label

I have a DDL which fetch data assigned users from DB. I want to give ability to type it in or select from DDL.
here is my view code

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 ui-front">
   <label class="control-label">Assigned To</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OpsMonUser, new SelectList(Model.OpsMonUser), new { @id = 
        "OpsMonUserDDL", @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Any idea how should I proceed further?

Comment: Use select2 if you want such a functionality. There is no need for new SelectList. Model.OpsMonUser is ok.

Comment: @Adlorem I have remove the part of code you suggested. Can I use Select2 inside my current code using @HTML.DropDownListFor()?

Comment: Select2 is jquery library that is capable of such functionality out of the box. Check it out https://select2.org/